# Getting incorrect `Login failed for user` during integration tests

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, unit-testing, integration-testing

I'm trying to do a few integration tests involving an SQL merge procedure through Entity Framework. I have a C# unit test with this in testinitialize:

```
[TestInitialize()]
public void MyTestInitialize() {
    if (Database.Exists("DefaultConnection"))
    {
        Database.Delete("DefaultConnection");
    }
    var people = new Person[]
    {
        new Person()
        {
            createDate=new DateTime(2005,01,01),
            dob=new DateTime(1995,12,25).ToString("M/d/yyyy"),
            firstname="Benjamin",
            lastname="Jacobs"
        },
        new Person()
        {
            createDate=new DateTime(2018,05,13),
            dob=new DateTime(2003,12,25).ToString("M/d/yyyy"),
            firstname="Kenneth",
            lastname="Cobb"
        },
        new Person()
        {
            createDate=new DateTime(2018,05,13),
            dob=new DateTime(2003,12,25).ToString("M/d/yyyy"),
            firstname="Ismael",
            lastname="Glover"
        }
    };
    using(MyContext db=new MyContext()){
        db.People.AddRange(people);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

And then I have a few test methods that test merging a few different kinds of data. I want to start with a clean test database like the above. When I run each test individually everything passes. The problem is that when I run all the tests, only the first one passes, and all the subsequent ones will throw an error.

This is the error message (lightly edited to remove identifiable info):

> Initialization method MergePeopleTest.MyTestInitialize threw exception. System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "MyDatabase" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user '[windows user]'..

Deleting and recreating the database is probably not the best approach (I'm open to hearing better ideas) but it seems like this should work. I've done it before and did not have this issue.

**Edit:** the error is thrown on the second test during `TestInitialize` on the line where it tries `db.SaveChanges();`. As best I can tell, the database was deleted but then it didn't automatically recreate the way code-first EF is supposed to.

Comment: That error message says that the login failed, not that it can't find the database. Check your connection string and your user permissions.

Comment: the connection string is correct. And the test works fine one at a time. It absolutely can't be the case that it doesn't have login rights.

Comment: How can that error message be that the database was dropped? It says "The login failed. Login failed for user '[windows user]'"

Comment: It must mean that it tried to login after the database was deleted but before it was created? I'm not sure. But in debug, at the time the error is thrown, the database does not show up in SQL Object Explorer

Comment: Why in the world would the database continuously be deleted? That seems like a pretty bad idea to me. Kind of defeats the point of a database. And that error is not the error message you get when establishing a connection and the requested database doesn't exist.

Comment: Idea is I have several tests to run, and I want each test to start with a clean database. So it drops and recreates the database between each test.

Comment: Does it run multiple times at once (e.g. do you run integration tests in parallel or as a result of a CI build?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not running in parallel, but I'm not all that familiar with integration/unit testing (obviously). I'm just using a .Net unit test project in visual studio. Go to Test->Run->All Tests

Comment: Sound like some kind of setup / tear down issue. If you don't have specific config for running tests in parallell you can be use they run in sequence. But please post you test code as well, I take it the tests are declared in the same class...